# Indicator of what's inside of curly braces

Tags: visual-studio-code, curly-braces

I was watching a video that which had a visual help to know what's inside of curly braces:

within curly braces

[image: 1]

does anyone know how to activate this?

I don't know exactly how to search it. I couldn't find it in the settings. Or is it an extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the `editor.guides.bracketPairs` setting. You can add

```json
"editor.guides.bracketPairs": true
```

to your settings.json, or if you only want the guide for the current line,

```json
"editor.guides.bracketPairs": "active"
```

Comment: Please check if the questions and your answers are duplicates.